# Thrift Server hangs when sasl authentication was enable in hive server2

Tags: authentication, hadoop, hive, thrift

When hive.server2.authentication property was set to any sasl authentication(LDAP, KERBEROS,CUSTOM) then thrift server hangs while connecting with the hive server2.
In java there is a predefined class in thrift TSasltransport to connect with sasl authenticated hiveserver2 but in .Net this class was not available.
How to Enable sasl authentication in thrift for .Net library.